# Fetch images tags from a specific webpage Div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, linq

I am trying to fetch images tags from a specific div in a web page. Here is the web page link [page link](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-Luxury-New-Fashion-Anna-su-3D-Blink-Diamond-Crystal-Pearl-Flowers-For-iPhone-4G/1951144778.html?spm=2114.11010108.13.4.uQlqFV)

I have used this code:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb(); 
var document = webGet.Load(txt.Text);
var infos = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='custom-description']")
            from link in info.SelectNodes("img").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("src"))
            select new 
            {
                LinkURL = link.Attributes["src"].Value
            };
lbl.Text = infos.ToString();
```

but it returns null value. 
Please tell me whats wrong in this code. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);
    var rateNode = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='class name']")
                        from link in info.SelectNodes("//img").Where(x=>x.Attributes.Contains("src"))
                        select new
                        {
                         link.Attributes["src"].Value
                        };

   // return View(lstRecords);


    string result;
    lbl.Text = rateNode.ToString();
    foreach (var a in rateNode)
    {
        int count=0;
        Image img = new Image();

        img.ID = count + "a";
        count++;

        img.ImageUrl =  a.Value
        Controls.Add(img);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Linq query you have written here is looking ok. But the problem here is div with id `custom-description`does not contain `img` element. Hence query returns null result.